# Magento 2 How to place an order after getting response from redirected url?

Tags: magento2, javascript, knockoutjs

Folowing is my ajax call in file:
Path: **/app/code/Nitesh/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/payment-method.js**

```
$.ajax({
dataType: 'json',
url: url_submit,
data: data,
async : false,
type: 'post',
success: function(result)
{   
    if(result != null) {
        flag_success = 1;
    } else {
        flag_success = 0;
        window.location.assign(url_redirect);
    } 
},
});
```

My placeOrder()  fuction is called when flag_success == 1;

```
if(flag_success == 1){
      this.placeOrder();
}
```

Now when I'm redirecting to **url_redirect** then I want to place an order after getting response from that redirected url.

Means I want to make value of **flag_success = 1;** after gettting back from that redirected url.

Also If there is any way to call **placeOrder()** from controller that also helps me. Because I'm getting response of that redirected url there.

If anyone want more information then I will provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside controller where u want to place order:

Use this classes:

```
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Type\Onepage;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
```

Create Variables:

```
protected $cartManagement;
protected $quote;
protected $resultRedirect;
```

In construct:

```
parent::__construct($context);
$this->cartManagement = $cartManagement;
$this->quote = $quote;
$this->resultRedirect = $context->getResultFactory();
```

Place Order:

```
$this->quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
$this->quote->getPayment()->setMethod('payfull');
$this->cartManagement->placeOrder($this->quote->getId());
```

Redirect to success page:

```
$resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirect->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
$resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/onepage/success', ['_secure' => true]);
```

Above code will place order and show success page if order is placed.

Answer (score 2):

The solution depends on your payment integration implementation. But anyway, it can be done in the following way:

1. Your payment js component should call `set-payment-information` API instead `payment-information` (default method for this WEB API entry point is `placeOrder` js function) because as I understand you don't want to place an order before you get a response from your payment provider. The example, how to call `set-payment-information` WEB API you can find in [PayPal PayflowPro](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Paypal/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/payflowpro-method.js#L88) js component.
2. After calling `set-payment-information` WEB API entry point you need to redirect to your payment provider from js component.
3. In your redirect controller, you can call all required services, which you need. As an example, you can look into [Braintree PayPal](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Braintree/Controller/Paypal/PlaceOrder.php) implementation. It validates quote and uses `\Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface::placeOrder` to place order.

Comment: Thanks alot buddy for ur reply and providing a way to do that. 
Ok I will see that and tell u after that what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for ur braintree link, from that link I have found solution.
Thanks buddy.